# expected object but string found in retrofit 1.9

Tags: android, web-services, http, error-handling, retrofit

Hello guys sorry for my English. 
Hi I am new to the Retrofit library, I am having problems parsing some json. I have looked at some other solutions on Stackoverflow but not having much luck with my problem. im trying to get a a simple webservice to work. any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated .My json file.`{"user":"1","sup_id":"105","seller_vfd":"1","sup_lmd":"1"}`

Request method

```
String email=editEmail.getText().toString();
            String password=editPassword.getText().toString();

            progressGenerator.start(btnSignIn);

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user", "seller");
            params.put("sup_email", email);
            params.put("sup_pwd", password);
            params.put("sup_seller_token", "www001");


            RestAdapter adapter=new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(baseUrl).build();
            ApiCallRetrofit apiCall=adapter.create(ApiCallRetrofit.class);

           apiCall.signUp(params,new Callback<Seller>() {
               @Override
               public void success(Seller seller, Response response) {
                   System.out.println("inside success"+seller.user);
               }

               @Override
               public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                   System.out.println("inside success"+error);

               }
           });
```

Seller.java

```
public class Seller {

public int user;
public String sup_id;
public String seller_vfd;
public String sup_lmd;
```

}

ApiCallRestrofit.java interface

```
public interface ApiCallRetrofit {


@GET("/signin.php?")
void signUp(@QueryMap Map<String, String> param, Callback<Seller> cb);


@GET("/forgot_password.php?")
void forgotPassword(@QueryMap Map<String, String> param, Callback<String> cb);

@GET("/forgot_token.php?")
void forgotToken(@QueryMap Map<String, String> param, Callback<String> cb);
```

}

the error i am getting is

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I understand the error is saying the data is an object and it should start with an array but I cant work it out.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution in my code, actual problem is here`@GET("/signin.php?")
void signUp(@QueryMap Map<String, String> param, Callback<Seller> cb);`
 i am giving "?" after signin.php but after removing this sign it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to post the unmodified response that Retrofit received before trying to parse? It sounds likely that you may have included `"` at the start of the JSON object.

Comment: i am not getting your answer can you elaborate it little more Please.

Comment: So I imagine the parser is looking for an `{` (BEGIN_OBJECT) at line 1 column 1 but found a `"` (STRING). This would be the case if your JSON object was `"{"user":"1","sup_id":"105","seller_vfd":"1","sup_lmd":"1"}"` instead of `{"user":"1","sup_id":"105","seller_vfd":"1","sup_lmd":"1"}`

Comment: but when i paste my link in web browser i get this as responce {"user":"1","sup_id":"105","seller_vfd":"1","sup_lmd":"1"} not this "{"user":"1","sup_id":"105","seller_vfd":"1","sup_lmd":"1"}"